# How to say "Peekaboo" when playing hide and seek

Tags: meaning, word

I have tried to find how to say "peekaboo" in chinsese when playing hide and seek.

I 've just found 门门! but I don't know it is corect or not.

Could you tell me how to say "Peekaboo!"  and "Play hide and seek!" in chinese?

PS It's a little game, often played with very little children to make them laugh. You cover the eyes or face of the baby and then you suddenly remove them and say "peek-a-boo!".

You can also say it to children. A child that was hidden and shows up in a sudden, can also say "peek-a-boo!".

Comment: I would suggest including a description of what peekaboo is in your as the non native English audience might not know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's not a suitable Chinese name for the game 'Peekaboo'.
Someone says its name should be 躲躲猫, but I'm not sure.
Anyway, if you just want to know what should be said when you show up in a sudden in the game, you can say any modal particles such as "啊!", "哈!" etc.

BTW: In Chinese 捉迷藏 usually means a game played by several children. One child is selected, cover eyes and make a countdown, and the others hide themselves in the period of the countdown. And then the child selected try to find out all other children.
捉迷藏 also can be said as 躲猫猫, 藏猫猫.

Comment: @nkm Sorry maybe it's not exact after saw your explanation of Peekaboo. I've fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much songyuanyao! Your answer, 捉迷藏, is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience we would say "鬼來了", which means "The ghost is coming".
We call the seeker as 鬼/ghost, and the ghost will announce that he is going to find others.

Comment: Ah! We can say that too. It's useful! Thanks a lot AngelLeliel!